# How to focus link in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my js code I want to auto focus a link inside modal:

```
$(document).on 'page:load ready', ->

  $('#layout_auth_main').

    on('shown', '.modal-destroy-dating', ->
      $(@).find('.btn-destroy-dating').trigger('focus')
    )
```

.btn-destroy-dating is a link decorated by bootstrap .btn
But it seems not work. So what is the right way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: did you try `$(@).find('.btn-destroy-dating').focus()`?

Comment: did you check whether the `shown` handler is executed?

Comment: @d_ethier I tried focus(), but not work either.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes shown handler is executed.

Comment: If the `shown` event is triggered, what is the console output of `$(@)`?

Comment: @d_ethier I got: [section.modal-destroy-dating modal fade in, context: section.modal-destroy-dating modal fade in, jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
0: section.modal-destroy-dating modal fade in
context: section.modal-destroy-dating modal fade in
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]

Comment: what is strange is if I write: $(@).find('.btn-destroy-dating').css('color', 'black') The .btn-destroy-dating's color will be change to black accordingly. But focus not work

Comment: Not being that familiar with coffeescript, I imagine it has something to do with the $(this) or $(@) object not being in the DOM during page load. While I can understand styling possibly working, events like focus are likely pickier. You could try a `$(document).find('.btn-destroy-dating').focus()`;